# How can I access 1 model params from another model's views?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have a view where I will be entering some info on a 'purchase' you could say, the actual model name is 'remission'. What I want is to display the client's info for which the id on the url belongs to in my  new_remission_path(@client). On the url I get '/remissions/new.3' so the client's ID is 3, but it won't let me display anything from the client's model info. I already added a foreign key 'client_id' to the 'remissions' table but I do not know if anything else is needed for me to be able to access a client model params from the actual 'new_remission_path(@catalog)' view

Comment: Have you added `belongs_to` in **remission** model ?

Comment: If you want to display data from the user, you have to store the user in an instance variable in `RemissionsController` in the `new` action.
Something like `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` or whatever is the name of the user id param.
Then in your view you'll have access to `@user`

Comment: @Shiko Yes I already have I did 'belongs_to :client'

Comment: I did that and I get this error 'Couldn't find Client without an ID'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So generally you might want to nest the route of the remissions inside the client. You would do that in config/routes.rb.

```
resources :clients do
  resources :remissions, shallow: true
end
```

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more info on nesting routes. The `shallow: true` gives you a way to access a remission in the show, edit, update, and destroy actions without having to specify the client it belongs to.

That would give you the `new_client_remission_path(@client)` where you would pass in the client. Your new action would then be on your RemissionsController (*app/controllers/remissions_controller*) and you could get the client by doing this:

```
class RemissionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @remission = @client.remissions.build
  end
end
```

Normally you might call just `params[:id]` but the nested routes send `:client_id` instead.

You will need a couple of relations in your models, too.

*app/models/client.rb*:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :remissions, dependent: :destroy

end
```

*app/models/remission.rb*:

```
class Remission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client

end
```

In your view, you should then be able to call @client to get information from that record.

Comment: Let me try this and I'll get back to you, thank you

Comment: So now I'm getting this error 'undefined method `client_remissions' for #<Client:0x000000000e635e58>'

Comment: You would call `@client.remissions` in your view. If you want to access an index for all of the remissions for the client, you would use `client_remissions_path(@client)`.

Comment: I should have specified. The error shows up on my remissions controller for 'client_remissions.build'

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, that should just be `@client.remissions.build`.

Comment: How can I comment a picture here? cause I get another error but thats in my remissions/_form.html.erb the error is    'ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `remissions_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000000ac5fc38>:0x000000000ac5dbe0>
Did you mean?  remission_path
               session_path):
    1: <div id="remision-form" class="remision-form-container">
    2:   <%= form_with(model: remission, local: true) do |form| %>
    3:     <% if remission.errors.any? %>
    4:       <div id="error_explanation">
    5:         <h2><%= pluralize(remission.errors.count, "error") %> proh'

Comment: Try `form_with(model: remission, url: [client, remission], local: true)`. The issue is that form_with is trying to send the form to `remissions_path` for the POST, but that doesn't exist. The actual path is `client_remissions_path`. You'll also need to model your create action like the new action. So first find the client, then `@client.remissions.build(remissions_params)`.

Comment: Okay that worked! thank you so much! you really helped me out